# Пропорционально отнимать у нецелого числа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой распространенный пример:

```
// стандартное значение input'a 100
$('body').on('click', '#input', function()
{
    $('#input2').val(parseInt($('#input2').val()) - 1);
    // на выходе получается 99, 98, 97...
});
```

А как реализовать подобное, но только для нецелого числа?

Пробую так:

```
// стандартное значение input'a 100
$('body').on('click', '#input', function()
{
    $('#input2').val(parseInt($('#input2').val()) - 1e-1);
    // на выходе получается 99.9, 99.9, 99.9
});
```

Из-за чего не получается решить подобную задачу стандартным способом?

Comment: @рони тут меняется в другом элементе, а не в том по которому кликнули

Comment: @ Grundy да незаметил убрал коментарий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо parseInt() используй parseFloat(). parseInt() округляет значение до наименьшего целого.

```
parseInt("99.9") == 99;
parseFloat("99.9") == 99.9;
```

Вот как это можно сделать:

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {
  var nowValue = parseFloat($(document.body).text());
  var nextValue = Math.round((nowValue - 0.1) * 10) / 10;
  $(document.body).text(nextValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
100
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает. Я немного усовершенствовал скрипт под свои нужды. Выглядит код так:

`$('body').on('click', '#input', function()
{
$('#input2').val(Math.round((parseFloat($('#input2').val()) - 0.1) * 10) / 10);
});`

Здесь отображается немного коряво код, я про свой имею ввиду((

Comment: @N0ob чуть поправил ответ, сбил "правильный ответ")